# How do I trim lines read from standard input on bash?

Tags: bash, trim

I want a bash way to read lines from standard input (so I can pipe input to it), and remove just the leading and trailing space characters. Piping to echo does not work.

For example, if the input is:

```
     12 s3c  
     sd wqr
```

the output should be:

```
12 s3c
sd wqr
```

I want to avoid writing a python script or similar for something as trivial as this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use sed to trim it.

```
sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//'
```

You can test it really easily on a command line by doing:

```
echo -n "  12 s3c  " | sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//' && echo c
```

Comment: Two sed processes is uncomfortably heavyweight.  Why not: `sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//'`?

Comment: That works against the data he provided.  I gave you points for that! :D

Comment: why not even `sed -r 's/ *(.*) */\1/g'`?

Comment: And `\s` instead of space in a case of TABs.

Comment: So, here's what I found: `sed -r 's/\s*(.*)\s*/\1/'` will mostly work, but I think it will not trim the end of the line, since the .* is greedy. I would try `'s/\s*(.*?)\s*$/\1/'`.

Basically, this looks for any whitespace up to the first non-whitespace, then any characters up to the first set of whitespace which is followed by the end of line. At least, that is the intent.

Comment: `sed` doesn't support non-greedy patterns and may not support `\s`. You would need to do something like: `sed 's/^[\t ]*\([^\t ].*[^\t ]\)[\t ]\+$/\1/'`. Note that Perl supports both non-greedy patterns and `\s`: `perl -ple 's/\s*(.*?)\s*$/$1/'`

Comment: Does anyone know how to trim line break in the end of string ?

Answer (score 25):

```
$ trim () { read -r line; echo "$line"; }
$ echo "   aa   bb   cc   " | trim
aa   bb   cc
$ a=$(echo "   aa   bb   cc   " | trim)
$ echo "..$a.."
..aa   bb   cc..
```

To make it work for multi-line input, just add a `while` loop:

```
trim () { while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done; }
```

Using `sed` with only *one* substitution:

```
sed 's/^\s*\(.*[^ \t]\)\(\s\+\)*$/\1/'
```

Comment: i like the simple utility approach. you need to fix syntax of while:  
`trim () { while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done; }`

Comment: Note that the point of this answer is 'just use the read command, it will trim by default'.  The use of echo is purely to match 'the output should be' test condition in the question.  To see how NOT to get the requested behavior or to understand why it is _possible_ this might not work, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314044/use-bash-to-read-line-by-line-and-keep-space).

Answer (score 5):

```
your_command | xargs -L1 echo
```

This works because `echo` converts all tabls to spaces and then all multiple spaces to a single space, not only leading and trailing, see example:

```
$ printf "  1\t\t\t2    3"
  1         2    3
$ echo `printf "  1\t\t\t2    3"`
1 2 3
```

The drawback is that it will also remove some useful characters like `\` `'` `"`.

Comment: This will fail if there are backslashes or quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Add this:
`| sed -r 's/\s*(.*?)\s*$/\1/'`

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but there is another simple and dirty way:

```
line=$(echo $line)
```

See this example:

```
user@host:~$ x="    abc  "
user@host:~$ echo "+$x+"
+    abc  +
user@host:~$ y=$(echo $x)
user@host:~$ echo "$y"
+abc+
```

Comment: This is broken: will fail if there are glob characters, and will also concatenate successive spaces. Not mentioning that `echo` is usually a bad choice (if, e.g., line starts with `-n`, `-e` or `-E`).

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -o -E '\S.*\S|\S'
```

Еxplanation:

- `-о` - print only matches
- `-E` - use extended regular expression syntax
- `'\S.*\S'`:

  - match the first non-space symbol, then **greedy** match any number of any symbols, then match a non-space symbol
  - or, if the first part is not matched (i.e. there are *no two* non-space symbols), match a single non-space symbol