# Use Bash to read line by line and keep space

Tags: bash

When I use "cat test.file", it will show

```
1
 2
  3
   4
```

When I use the Bash file,

```
cat test.file |
while read data
do
    echo "$data"
done
```

It will show

```
1
2
3
4
```

How could I make the result just like the original test file?

Comment: One can find useful script-line to prepend line numbers to stdio: `{ i=0; while read; do i=$(dc 1 $i + p); printf "%4
d  $REPLY\n" $i; done; }` It is compatible with old SH.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

```
IFS=''
cat test.file |
while read data
do
    echo "$data"
done
```

I realize you might have simplified the example from something that really needed a pipeline, but before someone else says it:

```
IFS=''
while read data; do
    echo "$data"
done < test.file
```

Comment: Because the script is reading into a single variable per line, any spaces within the data (after the first non-blank) are preserved regardless.  But the empty IFS preserves the leading spaces (in ksh and bash).

Comment: This is a place where you could write `while IFS= read data; ...`

Comment: @glennjackman I was starting to try `export IFS`..., good I read you tip!

Comment: You might want to use `IFS= read -r line` to avoid interpretation of backslashes.

Comment: Beware! If the process/script is trapped and `read` was cancelled while reading input (e.g. `Ctrl+C`), `IFS` may stay customized inside the trapped function/event. In addition, some might want `-r` `read` option to not process backslashes (escapes).

Answer (score 41):

Actually, if you don't supply an argument to the "read" call, read will set a default variable called $REPLY which will preserve whitespace.  So you can just do this:

```
$ cat test.file | while read; do echo "$REPLY"; done
```

Comment: This answer prompted me to closely read the documentation for `read`.

Comment: Note that if you have any backslash-escaped characters like `\n` in your source file (i.e. source code), `read` will convert them to just `n`. Use `read -r` to prevent this.

Comment: Note that this `$REPLY` solution doesn't work in ZSH, but the `IFS= read` solution works in both ZSH and Bash.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe [`IFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) is the key point as others said. You need to add only `IFS=` between `while` and `read`.

```
cat test.file | 
while IFS= read data 
 do echo "$data"
 done
```

and do not forget quotations of `$data`, else `echo` will trim the spaces.

But as [Joshua Davies mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314044/use-bash-to-read-line-by-line-and-keep-space/37797456#37797456), you would prefer to use the predefined variable `$REPLY`.

Comment: Just in case, `IFS` is not altered inside the loop that way, fortunately. Though, be careful! If the process/script is trapped and `read` was cancelled while reading input (e.g. `Ctrl+C`), `IFS` may stay customized inside the trapped function/event.
In addition, some might want `-r` `read` option to not process backslashes (escapes).

Answer (score 4):

Just to complement DigitalRoss's response.

For that case that you want to alter the [IFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) just for this command, you can use parenthesis. If you do, the value of IFS will be changed only inside the subshell.
Like this:

```
echo '  word1
  word2' |  ( IFS='' ; while read line ; do echo "$line" check ; done ; )
```

The output will be (keeping spaces):

```
  word1 check
  word2 check
```

Comment: Even though the unset `IFS` already salvages this particular example, you should still quote `"$line"`.  In a real world example, the value could still contain shell wildcards and what not.

Comment: **Wrong**, so downvoted!  **Use `IFS='' read -r line` instead!**  In your example the Pipe runs the `{..}` in a subshell!  Like `IFS=' '; ( IFS='' ); echo "=$IFS="` which prints `= =` (note the SPC).  In contrast `IFS=' '; { IFS=''; }; echo "=$IFS="` prints `==` (IFS from within `{..}`).  However I'd rather recommend: `fullread() { local IFS=''; read -r $1; }` or `IFS='' read -r line` (there is no `;' between `IFS=''` and `read`.  In shells `VAR=val cmd args..` is how you alter the environment for just one command (this works for builtins like `read`, too).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, Tino.
Try `cat -etv <<<"$IFS" ; echo word1 | { IFS=''; cat -etv <<<"$IFS" ; } ; cat -etv <<<"$IFS" ;`.
The subshell didn't change the IFS outside the block as I expected.
Can you elaborate?

Comment: The pipe creates a subshell. This causes the IFS assignment to be local to the pipe. The only thing the curly braces do is group the IFS assignment with the loop. The correct way top do this is with `echo '...' | while read -r ...` Everything Tino said is correct.

Comment: I see. So even though my code worked, it was because of the pipe, not the curly braces.
I changed to use a subshell explicitly with parenthesis, which would work for any case.

Comment: I didn't get Tino's solution to work with a pipe (`IFS='' read -r line`), though.

Answer (score 0):

`read data` will split the data by *[IFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator)*, which is typically " \t\n". This will preserve the blanks for you:

```
var=$(cat test.file)
echo "$var"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use a good file parsing tool, like [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
awk '{
  # Do your stuff
  print 
}' file
```