# Bash redirect stdout to function

Tags: bash, logging, stdout

I have 2 log functions:

```
log_msg()
{
    if [ ! -e $LOG_FILE ]; then
        touch $LOG_FILE
        chmod 0640 $LOG_FILE
    fi

    echo "$(date +'[%Y-%m-%d %T]') $1" >> $LOG_FILE
}
log_stream()
{
    while read data; do
        printf "$(date +'[%Y-%m-%d %T]') $data" >> $LOG_FILE
    done
}
```

In order to log msg:

```
log_msg "Hello World!";
```

In order to log stdout of another function I tried to do:

```
bgcommand --a --b 2>&1 > log_stream &
```

But it's not working.

I've found the function to log pipe at this question:
[Pipe output to bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454343/pipe-output-to-bash-function)
But something is missing.

Comment: If you are using `bash` 4.2, you can avoid invoking `date` by using `printf '%([%Y-%m-%d %T])T %s\n" "$1"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are writing to a file named "log_stream". The shell is not looking for a program/function name there. Try this:

```
bgcommand --a --b 2>&1 | log_stream &
#......................^
```

Or, redirect to a process substitution

```
bgcommand --a --b 2>&1 > >(log_stream) &
```

You might want to look into a utility named [`ts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ts.1.html) whose purpose is to add timestamps to it's input.

Comment: Seems ok use the "|".
But I decided to do not use it because this should affect "&" modificator and send only "log_stream" command in background instead of "bgcommand".

Can you confirm that use "|" will not affect the "&" only on last command in the pipe?

Comment: `&` will send the whole pipeline into the background