# Pipe cat results from named pipe to bash function

Tags: bash, macos, named-pipes, cat

I have this command:

```
 on_named_pipe_msg(){

 }

 export -f on_named_pipe_msg

 cat "ql_named_pipe" | xargs on_named_pipe_msg &
```

but I get this error:

> xargs: on_named_pipe_msg: No such file or directory

anyone know how I can call a bash function from the results of calling cat on a named pipe?

Comment: `xargs` doesn't know about exported functions.  Use a shell script instead of a function.

Comment: See [Pipe output to bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454343/pipe-output-to-bash-function) for more information on bash functions and stdin.