# Saving input before running command bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to save my entered commands and their respective outputs in a file.
What I'm currently doing:

```
mylog() {
    echo "----------------" >> ${PWD}/cmds.log
    echo "$@" >> ${PWD}/cmds.log
    # read foo # Tried reading the piped value in to
    # echo "$foo" >> ${PWD}/cmds.log
    # MYCMD="${@}"
    # echo "$MYCMD" >> ${PWD}/cmds.log
    "$@" | tee -a ${PWD}/cmds.log
}
```

It currently functions like: `mylog cat file.txt | mylog sort`
And the output in `cmds.log` is:

```
----------------
cat file.txt
----------------
sort
....
output from cat
...
output from sort
...
```

What I'd like is:

```
----------------
cat file.txt
....
output from cat
...
----------------
sort
...
output from sort
...
```

In the code, you can see I tried using read and following other method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454343/pipe-output-to-bash-function).
I also tried doing `VAR=${@}` but this just saved the command twice and doesn't execute it.

Any idea of how I can accomplish my goal?

Slightly related, I'm manually saving the terminals output like this, and not using `script` because the interactive shell causes lots of escape characters and such to be caught.

Comment: If you want to strip the interactive prompt, will setting `PS1` to `''` work? BTW, the output is like that because all fragments in a pipe are run in parallel, rather than sequential.

Comment: @dibery The type completition of my shell causes each variation that is suggested to be outputted, so PS1='' doesn't help. How could I run them sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modified script...

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mylog() {
    local output="log"
    
    # This is the key part right here. The 'tac' command here
    # prints stdin in reverse. To do this, it must read _all_
    # of stdin, so it buffers until it reads everything. Of course,
    # we must use two 'tac's so stdin doesn't actually get reversed.
    # You could also use `sponge(1)` here, but that does not come standard
    # on all Linux distributions / MacOS
    local buffer="$("$@" | tac | tac)"

    # Nothing below will be printed until 'buffer' is completely filled with stdin
    {
        echo "----------------"
        echo "$@"
        echo "----------------"
        echo "$buffer"
        echo
    } >> "$output"

    printf "%s" "$buffer" 
}

rm -f log
mylog cat file.txt | mylog sort >/dev/null
```

The resulting `log`

```
----------------
cat file.txt
----------------
bravo
alfa
charlie
delta
echo

----------------
sort
----------------
alfa
bravo
charlie
delta
echo
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the code and the explanation!