# How to stop read stripping spaces

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to parse a file, changing a line here and there. I have a simple loop like this:

```
while read line; do
  if *condition* then ; 
    echo *someChangedOutput* >> newfile
  else
    echo "$line" >> newfile
  fi
done < oldfile
```

My problem is that most of the lines in "*oldfile*" have leading spaces.  When I read them into the variable `line`, the leading spaces get stripped off - and so are missing when I echo `"$line"` to "*newfile*"

For instance, if "*oldfile*" is:

```
line1
      line2
   line3
```

"*newfile*" gets created as

```
line1
line2
line3
```

How can I read a line from a file WITHOUT having the leading spaces stripped?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314044/use-bash-to-read-line-by-line-and-keep-space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001. You need to unset `IFS` to avoid stripping off leading and trailing whitespace, and you most probably also want to use `-r`:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    do_something_with "${line}"
done
```

Comment: The `-r` stops the backslash character from being considered an escape char - which turned out to be necessary in my situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use read like this with special variable `REPLY`:

```
while IFS= read -r; do
  if *condition* then
    echo *someChangedOutput*
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
  fi
done < oldfile >> newfile
```

Comment: I believe you got downvotes because the question was : how to stop the read from stipping spaces (at the beginning/end of the input) and your answer didn't address that. ie, it should loop a `IFS= read -r` instead of just a `read`. Aditionnaly:  you should replace : `echo "$REPLY"` with : `printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"` to avoid some problems (for ex: if the REPLY starts with a `-` ...) see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: @OlivierDulac: Thanks mate for your valuable comment. I have made thse changes in my answer.