# Space between a path is not working when read line by line in Shell

Tags: shell, sh

I have an issue with a script that a file has multiple lines and some lines having space between two strings. While I read it line by line, the whole line is not reading and instead it delimit by space the second half only reading..

```
files.txt

/the/path/to/the/file.txt 
/new/first name/path/to/file2.txt

for line in `cat "files.txt"`
 do
  echo "$line"
 done
```

Output:
/the/path/to/the/file.txt
name/path/to/file2.txt

it is not showing the whole path if it has space. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37797456/3657941).

Comment: Thanks Dave. it works.