# How to loop over jq unique array in bash?

Tags: bash, jq

I'm trying to loop over unique names and commit messages from a github json object.  However when there are spaces in the arrays bash will treat them as individual array items

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

commits='[
  {
    "author": {
      "email": "email@example.com",
      "name": "Chris",
      "username": "chris"
    },
    "committer": {
      "email": "email@example.com",
      "name": "Chris",
      "username": "chris"
    },
    "message": "commit message 1"
  },
  {
    "author": {
      "email": "email@example.com",
      "name": "John",
      "username": "jdoe"
    },
    "committer": {
      "email": "email@example.com",
      "name": "John",
      "username": "jdoe"
    },
    "message": "commit message 2"
  },
    {
    "author": {
      "email": "email@example.com",
      "name": "John",
      "username": "jdoe"
    },
    "committer": {
      "email": "email@example.com",
      "name": "John",
      "username": "jdoe"
    },
    "message": "commit message 3"
  }
]'

authors=$( jq -rc '[.[].author.name] | unique | @sh' <<<"${commits}" )
echo "authors: $authors"

# this works
for author in $authors
do
  echo "author: $author"
done

echo "------------"

# this does not
messages=$( jq -rc '[.[].message] | unique | @sh' <<<"${commits}" )
echo "messages: $messages"

for message in $messages
do
  echo "message: $message"
done
```

Which outputs

```
authors: 'Chris' 'John'
author: 'Chris'
author: 'John'
------------
messages: 'commit message 1' 'commit message 2' 'commit message 3'
message: 'commit
message: message
message: 1'
message: 'commit
message: message
message: 2'
message: 'commit
message: message
message: 3'
```

While I expect:

```
authors: 'Chris' 'John'
author: 'Chris'
author: 'John'
------------
messages: 'commit message 1' 'commit message 2' 'commit message 3'
message: 'commit message 1'
message: 'commit message 2'
message: 'commit message 3'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Bash to read line by line and keep space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314044/use-bash-to-read-line-by-line-and-keep-space)

Comment: If that does, I'm not sure how... it is not using an array from `jq` and I'm not reading line by line.  But I am fairly terrible with bash so you never know...

Comment: `readarray -d ''  messages < <(jq -j '.[].message + "\u0000"' <<<"${commits}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works with change ' ' to '_' and back

```
messages=$( jq -rc '[.[].message] | unique | @sh' <<<"${commits}" )
messages="${messages// /_}"
messages=(${messages//"'_'"/"' '"})
echo "messages: ${messages[@]//_/ }"
for message in "${messages[@]//_/ }"
do
  echo " message: $message"
done
```

Or like this

```
IFS=$'\n' messages=( $(jq -rc '.[].message' <<<"${commits}") )
printf   "messages: "; printf "'%s' " "${messages[@]}"; echo
printf   " message: '%s' \n"          "${messages[@]}"
```

And we could do something like that

```
     IFS=$'\n'
 authors=($(jq -rc '.[].author.name' <<<"${commits}"))
messages=($(jq -rc '.[].message'     <<<"${commits}"))
printf " authors | "; printf "'%s' " "${authors[@]}" ; echo
printf "  author | '%s' \n"          "${authors[@]}"
echo   "---------+---------"
printf "messages | "; printf "'%s' " "${messages[@]}"; echo
printf " message | '%s' \n"          "${messages[@]}"
```

To output like this

```
 authors | 'Chris' 'John' 'John' 
  author | 'Chris' 
  author | 'John' 
  author | 'John' 
---------+---------
messages | 'commit message 1' 'commit message 2' 'commit message 3' 
 message | 'commit message 1' 
 message | 'commit message 2' 
 message | 'commit message 3'
```

Comment: Thank you for the submission! That works for my specific example, but if a user commits a message with a variable name using underscores it would get stripped.  I suppose you could use something like `__~~__` instead in hopes no one would ever use that sequence of characters, but seems like there has to be an easier way between jq/bash.  I'll mark as answer if that does not turn out to be the case :)

Comment: Agree about the caveats but ++ for best use of `//_/` that been posted here (ever?!). Also, I would advise against using `~` as it has various uses as a metachar in *nixLand. Good luck to all.

Comment: thx @Ivan, the IFS route works perfectly.  Also answers my next question of how not to output the quotes, so double thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

Use `readarray` (Bash 4+) to map null delimited output from `jq`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

commits='[
  {
    "author": {
      "email": "email@example.com",
      "name": "Chris",
      "username": "chris"
    },
    "committer": {
      "email": "email@example.com",
      "name": "Chris",
      "username": "chris"
    },
    "message": "commit message 1"
  },
  {
    "author": {
      "email": "email@example.com",
      "name": "John",
      "username": "jdoe"
    },
    "committer": {
      "email": "email@example.com",
      "name": "John",
      "username": "jdoe"
    },
    "message": "commit message 2"
  },
    {
    "author": {
      "email": "email@example.com",
      "name": "John",
      "username": "jdoe"
    },
    "committer": {
      "email": "email@example.com",
      "name": "John",
      "username": "jdoe"
    },
    "message": "commit message 3"
  }
]'

readarray -d '' authors < <(jq -j '.[].author.name + "\u0000"' <<<"${commits}")

for author in "${authors[@]}"
do
  echo "author: $author"
done

echo "------------"

readarray -d '' messages < <(jq -j '.[].message + "\u0000"' <<<"${commits}")

for message in "${messages[@]}"
do
  echo "message: $message"
done
```

Alternatively, if you have an older Bash version without `readarray` or `mapfile` you may separate the strings with the ASCII control character ETX (End of TeXt `03`) and use `read` instead like this:

```sh
IFS=$'\03' read -d '' -ra authors < <(jq -j '.[].author.name + "\u0003"' <<<"${commits}")

IFS=$'\03' read -d '' -ra messages < <(jq -j '.[].message + "\u0003"' <<<"${commits}")
```

It is also possible to populate both arrays from a single `jq` call:

```sh
# Populates both arrays from a single jq call
{
  IFS=$'\03' read -r -d '' -a authors
  IFS=$'\03' read -r -d '' -a messages
} < <(jq -j '([.[].author.name] | unique | .[] + "\u0003"), "\u0000",  ([.[].message] | unique | .[] + "\u0003")' <<<"${commits}")
```

Explanation:

- `[.[].author.name] | unique | .[] + "\u0003"`:
  Output an `ETX (03)` delimited list of unique author names.
- `"\u0000"`: insert a null delimiter
- `[.[].message] | unique | .[] + "\u0003"`:
  Output an `ETX (03)` delimited list of unique messages.
- Feeds the whole output of `jq` to a command group with two `read` commands.
  Each `read` will stop at the null delimiter or end of the stream.

```sh
{
  IFS=$'\03' read -r -d '' -a authors
  IFS=$'\03' read -r -d '' -a messages
}
```

Comment: Thanks pretty clean! In the first section I think you left out the unique part `readarray -d '' authors < <(jq -j '[.[].author.name] | unique | .[] + "\u0000"' <<<"${commits}")` seems to work.  However that IFS is even tidier, ty!