# How to escape asterisk symbol '*' in an array in bash shell

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

I am a newbie for the bash shell. The previous developer created the following codes to use a shell script to deploy AWS cloudformation stack.

1. Read a json file and using `jq` to convert it to an array called `parameters`
2. Using `${parameters[@]}` to spread into key=value pair strings

The problem is one array value is `cron(0 20-6 * * ? *)`. The deploy.sh will convert the `*` as current directory file names such as `cron(0 20-6 CODEOWNERS README.md CODEOWNERS README.md ? *)`

**My question:**
How can I let my deploy.sh to escape the `*` characters when calling `${parameters[@]}`.

Here are the example codes:

dev.json

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "Environment": "dev",
    "CrawlerScheduleExpression": "cron(0 20-6  * * ? *)"
  },
  "Tags": {
    "Severity": "High",
    "Environment": "dev",
    "DeletionPolicy": "Retain"
  }
}
```

deploy.sh

```
parameters=($(jq -r '.Parameters | keys[] as $k | "\($k)=\(.[$k])"' "dev.json")) 
tags=($(jq -r '.Tags | keys[] as $k | "\($k)=\(.[$k])"' "${conf_file}"))

    aws cloudformation deploy \
    --s3-bucket ${BUILD_ARTIFACTS_BUCKET} \
    --s3-prefix ${PROJECT_NAME} \
    --template-file ${template} --stack-name ${STACK_NAME} \
    --parameter-overrides "${parameters[@]}" \ # Environment=dev CrawlerScheduleExpression=cron(0 20-6 CODEOWNERS README.md CODEOWNERS README.md ? *) 
    --tags "${tags[@]}"
```

Comment: The question is unrelated to `make` per se. You are trying to ask about Bash arrays, and the syntax for those is Bash syntax. But `make` does not support Bash as the shell other than by explicitly setting `SHELL=/bin/bash` and even then your question does not seem to be repeatable. The double quotes you already have will do what you are actually asking, but it looks like you managed to populate the array earlier without quoting.

Comment: Actually that doesn't look like a valid `Makefile` at all.

Comment: The problematic code is `parameters=($(jq -r '.Parameters | keys[] as $k | "\($k)=\(.[$k])"' "dev.json"))`; the shell will perform wildcard expansion on the output from `jq`. It's not clear why you want this to be an array at all; but again, none of this really makes sense in the context of a Makefile.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Yes, this is a bash script instead of the makefile. I have changed my the and contents to match my question.

Comment: I think you should be ok if you added quotes in the `jq` mapping as follows : `parameters=($(jq -r '.Parameters | keys[] as $k | "\($k)=\'\(.[$k])\'"' "dev.json"))`. The point is to change the `a=b\nc=d` output of jq into `a='b'\nc='d'` which will prevent the values of those variables from being expanded

Comment: @Aaron That doesn't work at all. First, you can't put single-quotes in a single-quoted string by escaping them (you'd need to end the single-quoted section, *then* use an escaped single-quote, and then probably start a new single-quoted section). Second, the shell doesn't parse quotes in command substitutions, so even if you output them they don't solve the problem.

Comment: @Tao Would the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60226618/how-to-loop-over-jq-unique-array-in-bash) work in your situation? (Note: I'd recommend Léa Gris' suggestions over the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I have to disable the bash wildcard expansion to achieve my goal :(

`set noglob on`