# How to preserve leading spaces whern reading from a here-document with read?

Tags: bash, input, trim

When using the following

```
read -r -d '' VAR <<EOF
  first line
  second line
EOF
echo "$VAR"
```

the leading spaces in the first line are trimmed:

```
first line
  second line
```

How can I echo the leading spaces in the first line and get the following?

```
  first line
  second line
```

Please note that this is a simplified example and that I need to use `here document`!

Comment: Just prepend `IFS= ` before `read`: `IFS= read ...`. Note that this will preserve also the last newline.

Comment: Reading from a file or here-document is not different. There are answers here to your question: [Use Bash to read line by line and keep space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314044/use-bash-to-read-line-by-line-and-keep-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `read` into a variable you specify as a parameter, the leading and ending characters in `IFS` are considered delimiters and thus are removed.

First solution: empty IFS temporarily

```
IFS= read -r -d '' VAR <<EOF
  first line
  second line
EOF
printf '%s\n' "$VAR"
```

Second solution (non-portable): don't specify a variable and Bash will use the default variable `REPLY`

```
read -r -d '' <<EOF
  first line
  second line
EOF
printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
```